# Sending Lightning Email Template from Apex code

Tags: email-template, apex-email-service

I'm trying to send an Lightning Email Template via APEX, have not been able to do so.
I get no exception or anything, just no email gets sends. With various `System.debug()` commands I'm able to retrieve the template, but nothing get's send out, if I switch to using an older template `Classic Email Templates` that works. Are there limitations to use `Lightning Email Template` within an APEX code?

```
Contact con = new Contact();
con.Id = '0037R00002zbgFKQAY';
con.AccountId = '0017R00002bYqbLQAS';
con.Email = 'myname@myname.com';

sendEmailTemplate(con, 'Business_Portal_User_Exists_TEST_1633965573772', null);
public static void sendEmailTemplate(Contact contact, String emailTemplateDeveloperName, Map<String, String> manipulateHTMLTemplate) {
    System.debug(contact);
    EmailTemplate emailTemplate = [SELECT Subject, DeveloperName, Name, Id, HtmlValue FROM EmailTemplate WHERE DeveloperName =: emailTemplateDeveloperName];
    System.debug(emailTemplate);
    
    List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage> emails = new List<Messaging.SingleEmailMessage>();
    Messaging.SingleEmailMessage message = new Messaging.SingleEmailMessage();
    message.setTargetObjectId(contact.Id); 
    message.setSenderDisplayName(emailTemplate.Subject); 
    message.setUseSignature(false); 
    message.setBccSender(false); 
    message.setSaveAsActivity(false);
    message.setTemplateID(emailTemplate.Id); 
    /*if (manipulateHTMLTemplate == null || manipulateHTMLTemplate.isEmpty()) {
        System.debug('usirng emailTemplate.Id');
        message.setTemplateId(emailTemplate.Id); 
    } else {
        message.setHtmlBody(manipulateHTMLTemplate(emailTemplate, manipulateHTMLTemplate).HtmlValue);
    }*/
    message.setWhatId(contact.AccountId);
    message.toAddresses = new String[] { contact.Email };
    emails.add(message);
    //system.debug(message);
    System.debug('-------');
    System.debug(contact.Email);

    try {
        Messaging.SendEmailResult[] results = Messaging.sendEmail(emails);
        if (results[0].success) {
        } else {
            IceLog.error('Error email failed to send: ' + results[0].errors[0].message, 'IceUtils', 'sendEmailTemplate');
        }
    } catch (System.EmailException ex) {
        IceLog.error('Error email exception, message failed to send: ' +ex, 'IceUtils', 'sendEmailTemplate');
    }       
}

private static EmailTemplate manipulateHTMLTemplate(EmailTemplate emailTemplate, Map<String, String> manipulateHTMLTemplate) {
    for (String key : manipulateHTMLTemplate.keySet()) {
        emailTemplate.HtmlValue = emailTemplate.HtmlValue.replace(key, manipulateHTMLTemplate.get(key));
    }
    System.debug(emailTemplate);
    return emailTemplate;
}
```

Comment: Hello did you ever resolve this?

Answer (score 0):

This can be resolved by using the renderer in the [Messaging Class :](https://developer.salesforce.com/docs/atlas.en-us.apexref.meta/apexref/apex_classes_email_outbound_messaging.htm#apex_System_messaging_renderStoredEmailTemplate)

easiest way is on creation of the message with:

```
Messaging.SingleEmailMessage messageFromLightningTemplate = Messaging.renderStoredEmailTemplate(<TemplateId>, <ContactId>,<RecordId>);
```